# How to disable automatic Windows backups?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, windows-backup

I have a couple of Windows 7 machines at work. I have them both set up to perform weekly backups to a network drive. I'd like to temporarily disable that, while I'm on vacation. But I don't know how.

I've gotten into `Backup and Restore`. It lists  the backup destinations and I see the one that I'd like to disable. But there's no Enable or Disable functionality that I can see there.

**Q:** How do I disable the scheduled weekly backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dialog is just to make things easier. Behind the scenes it creates a regular Task Scheduler task which you can modify. It is listed under Task Scheduler -> Task Scheduler Library -> Microsoft -> Windows -> WindowsBackup -> AutomaticBackup task. Change the start date past your vacation (leave the rest alone).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Control Panel » Backup and Restore` and follow the screenshots to disable your schedule

[image]

(Click through the next two screens)

[image]
[image]

Comment: "Every Samstag at 19:00" That's an interesting mix of languages.

Comment: :D - Windows can't translate non-english weekdays if you install the english MUI later. That bug is all over the whole system

Comment: Yes, I got the same thing myself when someone at work decided I should have a localized Windows installation but I wanted it in English... installing the English language pack only netted me half the UI in English, no matter how many global settings I made for "English".