# Change Windows 7 backup & recovery tool so it keeps 2 backups instead of one or indefinite backups

Tags: windows-7, backup

I'm using Windows 7 build-in backup & recovery tool and have [scheduled it to automatically create a system backup each week](https://superuser.com/a/626844/50173). So far so good

There you have two options on how many different backups WIndows should keep:

[image]

Both are unsatisfying because

- With option 1: The backup folder will grow tremendously over time
- With option 2: A single backup is not enough. At least 2 backups should be kept

Can I change this behavior somehow so Windows will keep 2 backups? Maybe via registry?

---

PS: If I use a normal [scheduled task and command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742083(WS.10).aspx), will the Windows recovery tool *see* and list this recovery if I'm in recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way of limiting it on the same drive.

My suggestion is that you partition your hard drive, point the back up to the new partition.

If you have a 1Tb drive, create a partition of 150Gb (so now you have a primary partition of 850Gb, and a secondary of 150Gb). Then format the secondary partition, and let windows assign it a letter.

This seems pretty clear:

http://www.wikihow.com/Partition-Your-Hard-Drive-in-Windows-7